# how to use the object variable inside string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm trying to create a string with a prefix variable which will dynamically allocate from the array of object but it shows UNDEFINED

this is my code

```
    app.post("/objectlooping",(req,res)=>{
    const myArray = [{"name":"venkat","number":"2345678900"}, {"name":"jhon","number":"2345678900"}, {"name":"selva","number":"2345678900"}];
    const message =`HI ${n}`;
myArray.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    var n=element.name;
    console.log(element.message); 
    
});
     
   });
```

can anyone help me to achieve this but this shows undefined

Comment: What do you expect it to return ? Since none of the elements have `message` key, accessing it via element.message returns `undefined`.

Comment: `n` doesn't exist when `message` is defined. Consider using `console.log(\`Hi ${element.name}\`)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use message fn instead of variable then call it like

```
const message = (name)=>`Hi ${name}`
myArray.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    var name=element.name;
    console.log(message(name)); 
    
});
```

Comment: yes its works but instead of declaring `{name}` than `${name}`

Comment: Good catch; edited.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly you're trying to log a message for each name.

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the objects in the array and return an array containing a  message for each name in each object, and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that array of messages up with a line break.

```js
const myArray=[{name:"venkat",number:"2345678900"},{name:"jhon",number:"2345678900"},{name:"selva",number:"2345678900"}];

const message = myArray.map(obj => {
  return `Hi ${obj.name}`;
}).join('\n');

console.log(message);
```